Finding the unique data in dataframe even data order varies between two dataframes
Hi all I want to take the differences between two dataframes,
Dataframe A                           Dataframe B 
-------------------- ------          ----------------------------
No|Name| iD| address| mail           No|Name| iD| address | mail \
-------------------- ------          -----------------------------
1 | Raj | 01 | xxxxx                 1 | Buv | 03 | lllll | NULL
2 | Kam | 02 | yyyyy                 2 | Kam | 02 | yyyyy | NULL
3 | Buv | 03 | zzzzz                 3 | Raj | 01 | xxxxx | NULL
4 | Ram | 04 | kkkkk
5 | Buv | 05 | ppppp

here I have two dataframes, Dataframe A has 5 rows, but Dataframe B has 3 rows, I want to get output of different entries in this dataset, for example , 
here expected output is :
3 | Buv | 03 | lllll  --- 3 is icluded because address content is mismatch.\
4 | Ram | 04 | kkkkk \
5 | Buv | 05 | ppppp \

I tried to concat both dataframes and tried to take the result out but I cant able to find the exected result
df_diff = pd.concat(\[df1, df2\]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

And on another hand as Dataframe A has whitespace and DataframeB has NULL value instead of whitespace,
I used df1 = df1.replace(r'^\\s*$', 'NULL', regex=True).replace({np.nan: 'NULL'}) to fix this NULL issue
The output I expect is :
3 | Buv | 03 | lllll  --- 3 is icluded because address content is mismatch.\
4 | Ram | 04 | kkkkk\
5 | Buv | 05 | ppppp


I wish to create a new dataframe df3 and would like to store the difference data in new dataframe, , Different rows will be there in the new dataframe, And where only cell mismatch on existing rows, I want to highlight that cell with yellow color or any color
